# Upload one part of dataset at a time in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dataset

I have a big dataset, its initially dimension is `(453732,839)`. In this dataset, I have subgroups that are related each other and those subgroups have variable dimension. Since I have to train an LSTM, each subgroup must be the same size, so I apply padding to each subgroup so that they are all the same length.
After padding, the dataset becomes about `2000000` rows.

So I'm executing the `model.fit()` function within a loop where the `model.fit()` is executed one for each part of the dataset. Inside the loop I'm padding online the part of the dataset to pass to the `model.fit()`, but at the second part, before the `model.fit()`, RAM fills up and I can't continue training.

This is the code in which I `pad` and `fit` the model:

```
training_set_portion_size = int(training_dataset.shape[0] / 6)
start_portion_index = 0

for epoch in range(0, 50):
      for part in range(0, 4):
        end_portion_index = start_portion_index + training_set_portion_size
        training_set_portion = training_dataset[start_portion_index:end_portion_index]
        training_set_portion_labels = training_set_portion[:, training_set_portion.shape[1]-1]
        portion_groups = get_groups_id_count(training_set_portion[:,0])
        # Scale dataset portion
        training_set_portion = scaler.transform(training_set_portion[:,0:training_set_portion.shape[1]-1])
        training_set_portion = np.concatenate((training_set_portion, training_set_portion_labels[:, np.newaxis]), axis=1)
        # Pad dataset portion
        training_set_portion = pad_groups(training_set_portion, portion_groups)
        training_set_portion_labels = training_set_portion[:, training_set_portion.shape[1]-1]
        # Exluding group and label from training_set_portion
        training_set_portion = training_set_portion[:, 1:training_set_portion.shape[1] - 1]
        # Reshape data for LSTM
        training_set_portion = training_set_portion.reshape(int(training_set_portion.shape[0]/timesteps), timesteps, features)
        training_set_portion_labels = training_set_portion_labels.reshape(int(training_set_portion_labels.shape[0]/timesteps), timesteps)
        model.fit(training_set_portion, training_set_portion_labels, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=False, epochs=1, 
                  batch_size=1, workers=0, max_queue_size=1, verbose=1)
```

*** **UPDATE** ***

I'm using `pandas` now, with `chunksize`, but seems the tensors are concatenating in the loop.

`pandas` iterator:

```
training_dataset_iterator = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/Tesi_magistrale/en-train.H', 
                                        chunksize=80000, sep=",", header=None, dtype=np.float64)
```

New code:

```
for epoch in range(0, 50):
      for chunk in training_dataset_iterator:
        training_set_portion = chunk.values
        training_set_portion_labels = training_set_portion[:, training_set_portion.shape[1]-1]
        portion_groups = get_groups_id_count(training_set_portion[:,0])
        # Scale dataset portion
        training_set_portion = scaler.transform(training_set_portion[:,0:training_set_portion.shape[1]-1])
        training_set_portion = np.concatenate((training_set_portion, training_set_portion_labels[:, np.newaxis]), axis=1)
        # Pad dataset portion
        print('Padding portion...\n')
        training_set_portion = pad_groups(training_set_portion, portion_groups)
        training_set_portion_labels = training_set_portion[:, training_set_portion.shape[1]-1]
        # Exluding group and label from training_set_portion
        training_set_portion = training_set_portion[:, 1:training_set_portion.shape[1] - 1]
        # Reshape data for LSTM
        training_set_portion = training_set_portion.reshape(int(training_set_portion.shape[0]/timesteps), timesteps, features)
        training_set_portion_labels = training_set_portion_labels.reshape(int(training_set_portion_labels.shape[0]/timesteps), timesteps)
        print('Training set portion shape: ', training_set_portion.shape)
        model.fit(training_set_portion, training_set_portion_labels, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=False, epochs=1, 
                  batch_size=1, workers=0, max_queue_size=1, verbose=1)
```

The first `print('Training set portion shape: ', training_set_portion.shape)` gave me `(21327, 20, 837)`, but the second gave me `(43194, 20, 837)`. I don't understand why.

**UPDATE 2**

I notice that `training_set_portion = pad_groups(training_set_portion, portion_groups)`, in some way, duplicate data.

Pad groups code:

```
def pad_groups(dataset, groups):
    max_subtree_length= 20
    start = 0
    rows, cols = dataset.shape
    padded_dataset = []
    index = 1
    for group in groups:
      pad = [group[0]] + [0] * (cols - 1)
      stop = start + group[1]
      subtree = dataset[start:stop].tolist()
      padded_dataset.extend(subtree)
      subtree_to_pad = max_subtree_length - group[1]
      pads = [pad] * subtree_to_pad
      padded_dataset.extend(pads)
      start = stop
      index+=1
    padded_dataset = np.array(padded_dataset)
    return padded_dataset
```

How can I do that?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a link in TowardsDataScience where they show you 3 methods to fix this problem by using a small library called `pandas` which is widely used for dataset processing. I hope it is of some help to solve your problem. Here is the link:-

```
https://towardsdatascience.com/3-simple-ways-to-handle-large-data-with-pandas-d9164a3c02c1
```

Regards,
Neel Gupta

Comment: Thank you! I updated my answer with a new problem using `pandas`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issues: there was a bug in my code.